# Vuejs 3 - How to send data to template from other hooks than data() and setup()?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

I'm somewhat new to Vue/VueX so there sure must be something I don't understand right.

I have a very simple component:

- It fetches a collection of items from VueX `mapState` (in `computed()`)
- In which I fetch a single item from (in `mounted()` at the moment)
- I then need to push that item to the template but I can't figure it out

The way I understand, we can only push data to template from `setup` or `data` methods but not from `mounted`, `created` hooks, etc. Does this sound right?

In the following example code, how could I send the `item` object I get from `items` in `mounted()` to the template?

I cannot do it all in `setup` since my `computed()` VueX `items` object isn't available yet in there. Any suggestion about how to correctly achieve this simple goal?

```
<template>
  <p>ID: {{ id }}</p>
  <p>Name:: {{ item.name }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // fetching items from vuex (works)
  computed: mapState({
    items: (state: any) => state.items
  }),
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    // parsing ID from route params (works)
    const id = ref(route.params.id || 'Plants')
    return {
      id,
      // this seems to be the proper way of pushing data to template:
      // item: { name: 'this works from here' }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // fetch item by id (works)
    const item: Plant = this.items.find(i => i.id === this.id)

    // TODO: I need to push this to the template but I cannot from here
    return { item }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for this case to define another computed property like :

```
export default {
 
  computed:{ ...mapState({//should spread the mapState in order to add other properties
    items: (state: any) => state.items
  }),
  item(){
    const _item: Plant = this.items.find(i => i.id === this.id)
    return  _item;
   }

 },
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    // parsing ID from route params (works)
    const id = ref(route.params.id || 'Plants')
    return {
      id,
     
    }
  },

}
```

or use purely the options api :

```
export default {
 
  computed:{ ...mapState({//should spread the mapState in order to add other properties
    items: (state: any) => state.items
  }),
  item(){
    let id=this.$route.params.id || 'Plants'
    const _item: Plant = this.items.find(i => i.id === id)
    return  _item;
   }

 },

}
```

and

```
<template>
  <p>ID: {{ $route.params.id }}</p>
  <p>Name:: {{ item.name }}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome,  Try always to not change data between options api and setup, use composition api just for complex situations and for reusable logic, for simple properties use just option api